# Can I invoke a webservice based on URL and method name?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a webservice http://localhost:51624/Service1.asmx which has a method

```
public object HelloWorld(object)
```

My requirement is simple or may be complex.

1. Don't add service reference
2. Don't use wsdl to generate proxy.

I want to call something like

```
WebService Ws = new WebService();
Ws.url = "http://localhost:51624/Service1.asmx";
Ws.MehtodName =  "HelloWorld";//Need to pass object type as parameter somehow.

object result = Ws.Invoke();
```

Thanks in Advance,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a class that builds the required XML, and then uses the `XMLHTTPRequest` object to send the XML to the webservice. This will effectively "call" the webservice and reply with another XML (which, if you're interested in the reply, you'll need to decode again).

Just browse to your `http://localhost:51624/Service1.asmx` URL, click a method and read the examples.

Of course this will only be doable generically as long as the webservice does not require any parameters. Or things'll get really tricky...

**EDIT**

I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304151/505893).